# CSS Selector to Hide Text Node But Not Other Child Elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

With CSS, how would I select the text `This Text` . I wish to remove/hide it.

I can't alter the HTML itself, only change the CSS.

```html
<h2 class="hello">
      This Text
     <span class="mark">05/03/2017 3:29 PM EDT</span>
 </h2>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just intend to hide the text, do something like this

```css
.hello {
  font-size: 0;
}

.mark {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="hello">
      This Text
     <span class="mark">05/03/2017 3:29 PM EDT</span>
 </h2>
```

Comment: Nice, this is way better than mine since you don't have the empty white-space where the text was.

Comment: Good idea, though it requires redefining font-size.

Comment: @StevenMoseley yes but shouldn't be a problem in a lot of cases. Its always best to define things like font size so they look similar across browsers.

Comment: @MehulMohan - Not sure what cases you're thinking of.  I've never seen a website that doesn't define h2 font-size.  In your case, if the base `h2` font-size is ever changed, the `.mark` font-size would also have to be updated.  The downside I'm talking about is that you lose font-size cascading by "reset" it in the `.hello`.  Nevertheless, it's a good, creative answer to a problem with no great solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another idea, using `visibility`, which won't override any `font-size` styling applied elsewhere.

The slight potential downside of this method is that it changes `.hello` to relative positioning, which may override some layout you've applied to it.

I think this is less likely than overriding font-size, though.

```css
.hello {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.hello .mark {
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="hello">
    This Text
    <span class="mark">05/03/2017 3:29 PM EDT</span>
</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of would be to override the `span` inside after hiding the outer div. Something like this:

```css
.hello .mark {
  visibility: visible;
}

.hello {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="hello">
  This Text
  <span class="mark">05/03/2017 3:29 PM EDT</span>
</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `font-size: 0` or `visibility: hidden` can be used to "hide" the parent.

Combining those methods will have great benefits:

- `visibility: hidden` hides the text in a manner that it won't be copied to the clipboard when selected.
- `font-size: 0` will take care of the space that would remain after manipulating the visibility. This could also be fixed by making the parent positioned relatively and the child absolutely + `top: 0`. However, messing with the positioning will probably cause problems - sooner or later.
- It can't be a bad idea to define the font size anyway.

```css
.hello {
  visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
}
.mark {
  visibility: visible;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="hello">
  This Text
  <span class="mark">05/03/2017 3:29 PM EDT</span>
</h2>
```

---

This combines [Steven Moseley's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43768531/css-selector-to-hide-text-node-but-not-other-child-elements#answer-43768688) and [Mehul Mohan's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43768531/css-selector-to-hide-text-node-but-not-other-child-elements#answer-43768587) answer.